# Components in Tab control

Tags: angular, routes

My app component contains a tab control constructed from 2 components:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', children: [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'timing'},
      {path: 'timing', component: TimingComponent},
      {path: 'fio', component: FioComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

When `index.html` is launched, the constructor of 'timing' runs because of the 'redirectTo'. I want also the constructor of 'fio' to run, because I want fio to register its object to a service. This service is used to pass information to the fio component.

Is it possible?

Comment: Seems overcomplicated. What is the purpose of this flow? Why not have `TimingComponent` interact with the service, and `FioComponent` (when it actually exists) pull data from the service?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have an 'Open' menu item in the main (app) component. It opens an XML file, converts it to json and should pass its info to all children (timing, fio). The HTML of each component contains several controls that display this data. What is the right way implementing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use route resolvers. In the parent '' route implement a resolver that handles processing of the XML, and in the children inject ActivatedRoute and subscribe to route.parent.data.

Comment: Hi. Can you please provide a sample code ?  Upon calling to ngOnInit of "son" it can access data in the parent. Am I right ?

Comment: I can't right now (typing it on my phone), but you can start with this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580436/angular-pass-resolve-data-to-child-routes