# How to pass object to <router-outlet> from Observable?

Tags: angular

I have a parent view that calls some child views like this:

```
  -->negozio.component
           -->moduli.component
          --->ecom.component
```

In the parent view `negozio.component` i get in `ngOnInit` some data from an API call through Observable like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profiloService.profilo(this.idNegozio).subscribe((profilo: Profilo) => {
      this.profilo = profilo;
      this.profiloService.dataProfilo = profilo; // trying to set profilo to shared object
    });
```

Then i was trying to set the gotten object in a shared public object that is in the service and to get it on init of other two components.

But in any case i get the `"undefined"` as the object is not passed correctly..

So in `moduli.component` and `negozio.component` i'm trying to do this:

```
  profilo: Profilo;
  constructor(public profiloService: ProfiloService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profilo = this.profiloService.dataProfilo;
    console.log(this.profilo);
  }
```

But as i've noticed the component is loaded before the Observable in `negozio.component` is gotten.

Here is my ProfiloService code if it could help

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfiloService {

  dataProfilo: Profilo;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private adapter: ProfiloAdapter) { }

  profilo(idNegozio: string): Observable<Profilo>{
    return this.http
    .get(`${Globals.API_URL}/profilo/${idNegozio}`)
    .pipe(map((data: any) => this.adapter.adapt(data)));
  }
}
```

PS: I've tried by using `BehaviorSubject` but i still wasn't able to get `profilo` in other components.

Comment: maybe resolving helps more in your case. Maybe my question some tme ago solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580436/angular-pass-resolve-data-to-child-routes

Comment: @enno.void if i create a resolver and i will call the ProfiloService in it, how should i access the data in the parent view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BehaviorSubject`, but you should understand that it has first emitted default value. You can use simple `Subject` to skip this first value and subscribe to it in your child components.